# How do I show a text related to a menu item on the statusbar using MainMenu?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls

A common UI pattern is to display text in the status bar that is related to the currently selected menu item.

In the past I have achieved this in winforms by creating an extender provider that adds a string property with the custom text for each menu item to be displayed in the statusbar.
This was achieved by adding event handlers to the *MenuStrips*  *MouseEnter* and *MouseLeave* events to display and remove the text.

The problem I am having is that I am now using a MainMenu control instead of a MenuStrip and since it doesn't derive from Control it doesn't have *MouseEnter* and *MouseLeave* events.

The MainMenu has a Click event which means that I can display my text on the statusbar but as far as I can see there is no way to detect when the mouse has left the menu item and remove the text from the statusbar.

My question is how can I implement this UI pattern using the MainMenu control? Specifically I would like to know how to detect when the mouse has left the menu item so that the text can be removed from the statusbar.

Note: The MenuStrip control is not an option as it doesn't use the operating system look and feel and I am trying to make my application fit in with this as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each MenuItem has [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.select%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) event.  Connect to it and change your status text accordingly.

Well, as for detecting exiting of the item, use the timer, Remember the `Rect` of the last entered `MenuItem`, then when (check on timer event) it goes out, cancel the text. Isn't pretty, but could work.

Comment: I am doing this and it works fine. The problem is getting rid of the text once the mouse has moved away from the menu item. Perhaps I should rephrase my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'm not sure how to get the Rect of the MenuItem but will take a look. Even if this is not possible I could just remove the text using the timer after an amount of time has passed.

Comment: @Benjamin - I guess you'll have to dig deeper here - go override OnDraw, capture the rectangle there, and so on.  Lots of working around for a simple thing, I guesss. :(

Comment: Yes it seems it is a lot of work compared to working with a MenuStrip. I am questioning how much I really need this feature now as I think my efforts will be better spent elsewhere. Your answer does address my question so I have accepted it as the answer. Thank you for your help.